# Strong Params and MassAssignmentSecurity Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails 3.2.x, I could do this in my User model:

```
attr_accessible :email
```

And the following code would raise a MassAssignmentSecurity error when run from the command line (since password_reset_sent_at is not accessible):

```
User.new(password_reset_sent_at: Time.zone.now)
```

Now though, with the switch to strong_parameters, the code above will execute without raising any errors.

I'm guessing that rails treats command line input of this sort as trustworthy, since it can only come from the developer. Should I consider this safe? I assume that an attacker would only be able to submit code like the above if he/she had command line access right? Just a bit confused, so much to take in these last few days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely consider it safe because if an attacker gets access to your rails app via command line security is completely gone anyway and he would have plenty of possibilities to maliciously change data in database.

With the `strong_parameters` gem you get the benefit to control mass-assignment in the controller which is the best place  to do this. One of its goals is to stop you from struggling with mass-assignment problems when you don't need the protection, e.g. in the console or in model tests.

Comment: Thanks, the strong params pattern has become second nature now after a week or so. I like the fact that you have complete control now.